# Wordpress plugin styles and javascript not loading (Admin Section)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So I can't figure out why my stylesheet and scripts are not working. I have styles in the stylesheet. and an alert in my script file. Please help. (My paths are correct. If I include them. It echos their contents.)

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Stock Manager
    */
    function my_admin_menu() {
        $page_title = 'Stock Manager';
        $menu_title = 'Stock Manager';
        $capability = 'manage_options';
        $menu_slug = 'stock-manager';
        $function = 'index';
        $icon_url = plugins_url('recycle.png',__FILE__);
        $position = 56;

        add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position);
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );
    // Styles
    add_action('wsm_styles','reg_styles');
    function reg_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_style('wsm_stylesheet',plugins_url('css/styles.css',__FILE__));
    }
    // Content
    function index(){
      include ("includes/content.php"); 
    }   
    // Scripts
    add_action('wsm_scripts','reg_scripts');
    function reg_scripts(){
        wp_enqueue_script('wsm_scripts',plugins_url('js/scripts.js',__FILE__));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER

The files needed to be added specifically for the admin section as shown below.

Also I made a few structure changes from the original post.

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Stock Manager
    */
    function my_admin_menu() {
        $page_title = 'Stock Manager';
        $menu_title = 'Stock Manager';
        $capability = 'manage_options';
        $menu_slug = 'stock-manager';
        $function = 'content';
        $icon_url = plugins_url('recycle.png',__FILE__);
        $position = 56;

        add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position);
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

    // Content
    function content(){
        include ("includes/content.php");
    }

 //This is where the styles and scripts is been included
 add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');
 function my_custom_fonts() {
   echo '
     <script src="/wp-content/plugins/stock-manager/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
     <link href="/wp-content/plugins/stock-manager/assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
   ';
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: WebFootprint Stock Manager
    */
    function my_admin_menu() {
        $page_title = 'Stock Manager';
        $menu_title = 'Stock Manager';
        $capability = 'manage_options';
        $menu_slug = 'stock-manager';
        $function = 'index';
        $icon_url = plugins_url('recycle.png',__FILE__);
        $position = 56;

        add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position);
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );
    // Styles
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','reg_styles');

    function reg_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_script('wsm_scripts',plugins_url('js/scripts.js',__FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_style('wsm_stylesheet',plugins_url('/css/stylestest.css',__FILE__));
    }
    // Content
    function index(){
     include ("includes/content.php"); 
    }   

?>
```

replace this `add_action('wsm_styles'` with `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts'`

Comment: Also I don't know why using 'wp_enqueue_scripts' would make a difference over 'wsm_styles' or 'wsm_scripts'.  The field you are suggesting I edit is just a name for the action.

Comment: But I do appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` frontend enque script

Comment: I did try your code. Including the updated version hey